# Webpack and Typescript - use /node_modules/.bin/tsc instead of global

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create a simple Typescript library that uses Webpack.  I have the following in my package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "ts-loader": "^8.0.1",
  "typescript": "^3.9.7",
  "webpack": "^4.44.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
}
```

In my 'node_modules.bin' there is a 3.9.7 version of tsc.  I also have a global version of tsc installed on this machine that is used for a few other projects (3.5.1).  My problem is that this project is using newer features of Typescript that aren't in the global version, and the global tsc is being used to do the transpiling (so I get errors).  How can I configure my webpack or ts-loader to use the local tsc and not the global one?

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "allowJs": true, 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new script on your `package.json` with the command that you have been doing to compile.

Let's say that you are using `tsc -p tsconfig.prod.json` from the command line.

Add to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.prod.json"
  }
}
```

Then next time you need to compile your project, just use the command `yarn build` if you are using yarn or `npm run build` if you are using npm.

That way you package manager will use `tsc` command coming from your `node_modules` folder

Comment: Hi Henrique... thanks for your response.  Right now the script I have for 'build' is:

"build-dev": "webpack --mode development"

So would I need to add your suggestion as the first thing to run, then run webpack to bundle the resulting js files?  I'm passing the 'index.ts' as the entry in the webpack config.  So I guess I'm just confused how this all wires together.